# PHP How to check if you can afford it?

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have this:

```
    $scCost = $row["gpsc"];
    mysql_query("
        UPDATE member_profile 
        SET points = points-$scCost 
        WHERE user_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($userid)."'
    ") or die(mysql_error());
```

That takes do the user´s points - scCost.

How do i check if the user can afford it or not? So, if the user has 30 and the $scCost is 40..

Comment: Am I too late to state that PHP is free? - surely I can't be the only one that read the question title this way ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this atomically by adding an extra condition to the query and using [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php):

```
$scCost = $row["gpsc"];
$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($user_id);
$sql = <<<END
UPDATE member_profile
SET points = points - $scCost
WHERE user_id = $user_id
AND points >= $scCost
END;
mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
  // they can afford it
}
```

This is substantially better than doing a `SELECT` followed by an `UPDATE`, which introduces a race condition.

**Caveat:** `mysql_affected_rows()` returns the number of rows that were *changed*. This is important to understand. If you pass 0 cost into this query you end up with:

```
UPDATE member_profiles SET points = points - 0 ...
```

`mysql_affected_rows()` will *always* return 0 in that instance because no rows where changed. So if 0 cost is a valid case, you need to filter this and not bother running the query at all.

Also this works well if you're updating one row but it gets a little more difficult if you want to modify several rows at once. Then you get into questions like:

- What if some "rows" can afford it but others not?
- Do you want them all to fail?
- How do you report on which ones couldn't afford it?
- How do you do all this atomically?

You may be best off doing one `UPDATE` at a time even though this normally isn't the recommended approach and certainly won't scale to thousands of updates at once.

Answer (score 1):

You must to get this data and check in `PHP` side before you do some updates.
In `PHP` you should check if this value is not less than `0` after minus operation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `points` is equal or more than `cost`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT points>=:cost AS canafford
FROM member_profile
WHERE user_id=:userid
```

Answer (score 0):

add a second where clause "AND points >= $scCost"
and check to see how many rows were modified. One row = they could afford it. Zero rows, they could not.

```
$scCost = $row["gpsc"];
    mysql_query("
        UPDATE member_profile 
        SET points = points-$scCost 
        WHERE user_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($userid)."' 
            AND points >= $scCost
    ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Jacob

Comment: This allows you to check and transact in one round trip. You should make sure that the function to get rows affected is working correctly on your server. I have always had it be reliable on MySQL but had different results with other DBs depending on how they were connected.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the users original points amount by doing a SQL query

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($userid);
$sql = "SELECT points FROM member_profile WHERE userid = $id";
$results = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($results);
if($row['points'] > $scCost) {
// Update Row 
} else {
// Throw error 
}
```